# How to convert an object in pandas to category or an int type to numerical

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion, categorical-data

[image]

I've used dataframe.dtypes to return data type of each column but it's not categorical nor numerical nor boolean. What should I do?

I've tried using series to create a categorical series but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
# convert column "marque" of a DataFrame
df["marque"] = pd.to_numeric(df["marque"])
```

You can also use it to convert multiple columns of a DataFrame via the apply() method:

```
# convert all columns of DataFrame
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric) # convert all columns of DataFrame

# convert just columns "marque" and "Modele"
df[["marque", "Modele"]] = df[["marque", "Modele"]].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```